# Linear Regression Python- not fitting

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
area_df2 = pd.read_csv("homeprices.csv")
    
data = pd.DataFrame({'area':[4600,4800,5200,6000,6500],
                         'price':[775000,800000,832000,862000,940000]},index=[5,6,7,8,9])
df3=pd.concat([area_df2,data])
a=df3.drop('price',axis=1)
model=linear_model.LinearRegression
model.fit(a,df3.price)
```

[Data Frame after concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVbC3.png)

### It is not fitting it showing the following error;

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 model=linear_model.LinearRegression
> ----> 2 model.fit(a,df3.price)
> 3 model
>
> TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: [reading this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares) will solve your problem within 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the linear regression model, you forgot the parenthesis "()" at the end:

```
model=linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

Then your problem will be solved.